# PUSH to ViewController from other viewcontroller which is presented as popover - WITHOUT STORY BOARD

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am NOT USING StoryBoard in my project. I have presented one view controller as popOver Style.

```
let vcOne                               = ViewControllerOne()
    vcOne.showCorrectionFactor          = true
    vcOne.modalPresentationStyle        = .popover
    let pop                             = vcOne.popoverPresentationController
    pop?.sourceView                     = self.view
    pop?.sourceRect                     = sender.frame
    vcOne.preferredContentSize          = CGSize(width: 400, height: 500)
    self.present(vcOne, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now i want to navigate to other view controller from ViewControllerOne() and with in this pop up.

I am doing it like

```
let vc = PairViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

But `self.navigationController?` is getting nil value. How can i achieve this without story board.

Comment: What is `self` in the second code snippet? `ViewControllerOne`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not embed `ViewControllerOne` in a `UINavigationController`, so of course `self.navigationController` is `nil`.

Just do this:

```
// embed it!
let navController                   = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vcOne)
// get the popover presentation controller from the navigation controller!
let pop                             = navController.popoverPresentationController
pop?.sourceView                     = self.view
pop?.sourceRect                     = sender.frame
vcOne.preferredContentSize          = CGSize(width: 400, height: 500)
// present navController rather than vcOne!
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper. This is working. But the navigation animation is not smooth. Any idea?

Comment: @TheDevInMe Hmm that's weird... Are you doing this on an iPad Simulator? iPad Simulators are quite laggy sometimes, on my Mac anyway. So maybe try it on a physical device. Other than that, I have no idea.

Comment: No @Sweeper i am checking it in iPad. But thanks for your answer

Comment: @TheDevInMe Try asking a new question. Remember to provide a [mcve].